# Conditional query in between Linq query

Tags: c#, linq

I don't know that it is possible or not.
i have search some links but didn't find the solution.

i have a linq query for getting some data from the database.
Now, In my Database in the table column Photo can have or can not have a Image.
it means Photo can be null also.

**so My Question is:**
is there a way rather than use if else condition in linq query that we can put my code like this:

```
DataTable Customer=ds.Tables["Customer"]
    if (Photo==null)
    {
        var items = (from d in Customer.AsEnumerable()
                                 where d.Field<string>("strHin") != string.Empty
                                 orderby d.Field<DateTime>("date")
                                 select new News
                                 {
                                     NewsItemId = d.Field<Int32>("intCustId").ToString(),
                                     HeadLine = d.Field<string>("strHin"),
                                     Photo = null,
                                 }).Take(Convert.ToInt32(limit)).ToList();
                    return items;

    }
    if(Photo !=null)
    {
        var items = (from d in Customer.AsEnumerable()
                                 where d.Field<string>("strHin") != string.Empty
                                 orderby d.Field<DateTime>("date")
                                 select new News
                                 {
                                     NewsItemId = d.Field<Int32>("intCustId").ToString(),
                                     HeadLine = d.Field<string>("strHin"),
                                     Photo = @"http://192.168.1.12:801/ImageById/" + d.Field<Int32>("intCustId") + ".jpg"
                                 }).Take(Convert.ToInt32(limit)).ToList();
                    return items;
    }
```

i don't want to use if else because i have already used many if else in my code.
is there a way that i can use this with linq query without repeatation of code.

Comment: Your making us play spot the difference... what is the difference between your two code blocks?

Comment: Right now, Im struggling to see the differnce in your 2 linq statements..

Comment: and theres nothing wrong with elses!

Comment: this code does work? It doesn't look to me. First, write code that actually works. Then think about refactoring.

Comment: sorry guys i hav edited my question

Comment: @Paul Grimshaw: i didnt notice to these comments, and i was looking for 2-3 mins to find out whats the diff between those blocks..

Comment: Now i think as @FosterZ edited this question do anyone has answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
var result=    (from d in Customer.AsEnumerable()
                             where d.Field<string>("strHin") != string.Empty
                             orderby d.Field<DateTime>("date")
                             select new News
                             {
                                 NewsItemId = d.Field<Int32>("intCustId").ToString(),
                                 HeadLine = d.Field<string>("strHin"),
                                 Photos = Photo==null?"":@"http://192.168.1.12:801/ImageById/" + d.Field<Int32>("intCustId") + ".jpg",
                             }).Take(Convert.ToInt32(limit)).ToList();
                return items;
```

Note: i have change variable name of anonymous from Photo to Photos coz its conflicting with outer Photo variable with inner anonymous type variable Photo

Comment: I do not even think you actually have to rename the `News` property/variable `Photo` (other than for readability). I believe the compiler is able to use the right `Photo` from the context.